# In Frappe Framework Bench Start commands stuck on Rebuilding data_import_tools.min.js on MacOS

Tags: macos-catalina, frappe

I'm new to frappe framework. I have followed the instructions given on the FrappeFramework's website and installed everything without any major problem. But after executing
`bench start`
it stands still on `Rebuilding data_import_tools.min.js`

I have even left my Mac running for hours and still it won't progress further. Moreover there is not error shown in the process. So I'm unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

So kindly guide. Thank You.

Attaching my command & it's o/p with this question.

```
user1@MacBook-Pro frappe-bench % bench start
WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!

This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`

/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
08:17:05 system           | redis_cache.1 started (pid=857)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
08:17:05 system           | redis_socketio.1 started (pid=858)
08:17:05 system           | worker_default.1 started (pid=859)
08:17:05 system           | socketio.1 started (pid=860)
08:17:05 system           | worker_short.1 started (pid=861)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=857, just started
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=858, just started
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # Configuration loaded
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.314 # Configuration loaded
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.315 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.315 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 * Running mode=standalone, port=13000.
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 * Running mode=standalone, port=12000.
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 # Server initialized
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 # Server initialized
08:17:05 redis_cache.1    | 857:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 * Ready to accept connections
08:17:05 redis_socketio.1 | 858:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.319 * Ready to accept connections
08:17:05 system           | web.1 started (pid=865)
08:17:05 system           | watch.1 started (pid=866)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
08:17:05 system           | redis_queue.1 started (pid=864)
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.327 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.327 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=864, just started
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:C 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.327 # Configuration loaded
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.329 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.330 * Running mode=standalone, port=11000.
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.330 # Server initialized
08:17:05 redis_queue.1    | 864:M 31 Jul 2020 08:17:05.330 * Ready to accept connections
08:17:05 system           | schedule.1 started (pid=867)
/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:844: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
08:17:05 system           | worker_long.1 started (pid=868)
08:17:05 schedule.1       | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
08:17:05 schedule.1       | 
08:17:05 schedule.1       | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
08:17:05 schedule.1       | 
08:17:05 watch.1          | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
08:17:05 watch.1          | 
08:17:05 watch.1          | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
08:17:05 watch.1          | 
08:17:05 web.1            | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
08:17:05 web.1            | 
08:17:05 web.1            | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
08:17:05 web.1            | 
08:17:07 web.1            |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
08:17:07 web.1            |  * Restarting with fsevents reloader
08:17:08 web.1            |  * Debugger is active!
08:17:08 web.1            |  * Debugger PIN: 351-662-683
08:17:09 socketio.1       | listening on *: 9000
08:17:12 watch.1          | yarn run v1.22.4
08:17:12 watch.1          | $ node rollup/watch.js
08:17:13 watch.1          | 
08:17:13 watch.1          | Rollup Watcher Started
08:17:13 watch.1          | 
08:17:13 watch.1          | Watching...
08:17:14 watch.1          | Rebuilding frappe-web-b4.css
08:17:14 watch.1          | Rebuilding frappe-chat-web.css
08:17:14 watch.1          | Rebuilding chat.js
08:17:15 watch.1          | Rebuilding frappe-recorder.min.js
08:17:17 watch.1          | Rebuilding checkout.min.js
08:17:17 watch.1          | Rebuilding frappe-web.min.js
08:17:18 watch.1          | Rebuilding bootstrap-4-web.min.js
08:17:18 watch.1          | Rebuilding control.min.js
08:17:20 watch.1          | Rebuilding dialog.min.js
08:17:21 watch.1          | Rebuilding desk.min.css
08:17:21 watch.1          | Rebuilding frappe-rtl.css
08:17:22 watch.1          | Rebuilding printview.css
08:17:22 watch.1          | Rebuilding desk.min.js
08:17:25 watch.1          | Rebuilding form.min.css
08:17:25 watch.1          | Rebuilding form.min.js
08:17:26 watch.1          | Rebuilding list.min.css
08:17:26 watch.1          | Rebuilding list.min.js
08:17:27 watch.1          | Rebuilding report.min.css
08:17:27 watch.1          | Rebuilding report.min.js
08:17:28 watch.1          | Rebuilding web_form.min.js
08:17:28 watch.1          | Rebuilding web_form.css
08:17:28 watch.1          | Rebuilding email.css
08:17:28 watch.1          | Rebuilding social.min.js
08:17:29 watch.1          | Rebuilding barcode_scanner.min.js
08:17:30 watch.1          | Rebuilding data_import_tools.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started running the Frappe development server. The output you see is just the logs of the processes started by bench.

The requests you send to your server will get logged here, prefixed with `web`. The watcher builds assets dynamically and its logs are prefixed with `watch`. Similarly, you can see the output of the scheduler and redis processes.

If you've created a new site and added it to your hosts file, you can visit your site from the browser. As per the logs you shared, you should be able to access the site at port 8000. If your site's name is `site1.local`, try accessing it at http://site1.local:8000.

To understand the bench architecture and usage, I'd recommend you checkout the [Frappe Framework documentation](https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en).